# Can I insert DatagridView configuration on module for minify Form1 code?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have program CRUD, and I design DataGridView like this

```
    Sub DG_Barang()
    With DataGridBarang
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .ReadOnly = True
        .DataSource = DT
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Kode Barang"
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Nama Barang"
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Jenis Barang"
        .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Harga Beli"
        .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Harga Jual"
        .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "QTY"
        .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Tgl Update"
        .Columns(0).Width = 110
        .Columns(1).Width = 238
        .Columns(2).Width = 120
        .Columns(3).Width = 120
        .Columns(4).Width = 120
        .Columns(5).Width = 50
        .Columns(6).Width = 100
        .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
        .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
        .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

can I create a module that contain these code and call it on form1?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, pass `DataGridView`'s reference to the method only

Comment: can you give an short example? sorry I'm new in VB.Net and still studying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Module Settings

    Public Sub DG_Barang(dgv As DataGridView)
        With dgv
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            'other code
        End With
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()

        Settings.DG_Barang(Me.MyDataGridView)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I try your code, and when I debug, show this error message : "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: You need to check your code, where you use indexes of columns (`.Columns(6).`). Some index is out of range. Debug your code line by line

Comment: when I remove all .Columns..... on module, program can run, but when I add one .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C" ,program error again. What should I do, I have table that have 6 column